# How to connect to a local mysql database on webswing?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, xampp, webswing

I am creating a java game and I need to upload it to web, I discovered the webswing that converts the jar to a web version, I tested it to jar without database connection and it worked, but when I try to connect to a mysql database it return a error:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dreamland`

[Error into webswing executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxtzW.png)

I am using xampp to localhost database and I don't know if it's because that it can not connect

[Picture of all applications on webswing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYmDX.png)

The "jogoDreamland" application is the one that's getting the error

[Configuration of "jogoDreamland"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcn3s.png)

I only modified these two, the class path I added the path to where my main class is on the project and on main class I added the package.formsLogin

[The buttons that causes the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hryW.png)

When I click one of these two buttons it returns the error from above, when I launch it on desktop, it runs normally and connect to the database, the problem is when I use it on webswing

[mysql connector version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znc53.png)

[The connection to the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twpbS.png)

[Code that the method on the button runs, that use the db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuxkU.png)

[Another code that the method on the button runs, that use the db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTP6e.png)

Currently, only these two methods are loaded when I click the button.

Comment: Please go through the [ask] and [tour] links to see how to best use this site, how to post code so that it can be tested by us (hint, images of code won't work for obvious reasons and instead code should be posted as code-formatted text). Also, I urge you to change your tactics entirely, to not use "WebSwing" but rather use languages that are optimized for web use and that are fully supported, such as HTML/CSS/JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At any point in time you should be aware where your application is running.

So if you run a Java Swing application on your desktop, it is running on your desktop computer. If you push this same application into WebSwing, it becomes a webapp that you have to install on some server. Via your browser you connect to that server to see the UI but it's still running on the server.

To get the database connection, the application has to connect to wherever your database is running. If you left that on the local computer, your server has to connect to the local computer. Probably it is better to install the database either on the same server or on a server close to the machine running the Webswing application.

You error message though indicates you wrapped your application but forgot to add the mysql jdbc driver.

Comment: I discovered now that when you generate a jar executable file it creates a lib folder with the connectior, I added the folder to the webswing folder with the jar and it worked, thank you for warning me about the mysql jdbc driver.